# React.js won't include className using states inside a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a react website in pure css (no bootstrap) with an open/close sidebar. To do this I need to set and change css classes for elements on the page and have their visual updates apply instantly. Working on a very simple example where there is a state `const [setShowGreenBox, showGreenBox] = React.useState('true');`
And I'm trying to have this applied/removed to elements to display css data

```css
.showGreenBox{
    background:green
}

.bigPinkText{
    color: pink;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import './SidebarColorsTemplate.css';

const SidebarColorsTemplate = ({ children }) => {
    const [setShowGreenBox, showGreenBox] = React.useState('true');
    
    //this.setShowGreenBox('true')

    return (
        <>
        <div>SidebarColorsTemplate Page Top Content</div>
        
        <div className='bigPinkText'>String classNames</div>
        <div className={"bigPinkText "+"showGreenBox "}>String classNames inside brackets</div>
        showGreenBox={showGreenBox}
        <div className={"bigPinkText " + (showGreenBox==='true' ? "showGreenBox" : "")}>ternary  operator logic</div>
        <hr></hr>
        {children}
        <hr></hr>
        <div>SidebarColorsTemplate Page Bottom Content</div>
        

        </>
    )
}

export default SidebarColorsTemplate
```

Comment: `const [setShowGreenBox, showGreenBox] =` You've named these backwards. The first one is the value, the second one is the setter function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple with `Template literals` and `Boolean`

```
import React from 'react'
import './SidebarColorsTemplate.css';

const SidebarColorsTemplate = ({ children }) => {
const [showGreenBox,setShowGreenBox] = React.useState(true);


return (
    <>
    <div>SidebarColorsTemplate Page Top Content</div>
    
    <div className='bigPinkText'>String classNames</div>
    <div className={"bigPinkText "+"showGreenBox "}>String classNames inside brackets</div>
    showGreenBox={showGreenBox}
    <div className={`bigPinkText ${showGreenBox?'showGreenBox':''}`}>ternary  operator logic</div>
    <hr></hr>
    {children}
    <hr></hr>
    <div>SidebarColorsTemplate Page Bottom Content</div>
    

    </>
  )
}

export default SidebarColorsTemplate
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a string in the state looks like a weird choice in this case, it makes more sense to do:

```
const [showGreenBox, setShowGreenBox] = useState(true);

<div className={`bigPinkText ${showGreenBox ? 'showGreenBox' : ''}`}>ternary  operator logic</div>
```

Another option would be to just do:

```
const [showGreenBox, setShowGreenBox] = useState('showGreenBox'); // you can set this to an empty string instead of using false, but it's riskier (you could accidentally set it to an unexisting style)

<div className={`bigPinkText ${showGreenBox}`}>ternary  operator logic</div>
```

Comment: the above option would reult in `<div className="bigPinkText false">ternary  operator logic</div>` when `showGreenBox` is `false`